# Flutter making DropDown widget with passing any structured data

Tags: flutter, dart

In this new `widget` i want to make new `DropDown` in flutter with passing any structured data, for example in that `extendedClass` is a `pairValue` class which i want to pass it here.

this code is not correct and i can't pass that correctly there

```dart
class CDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> dataClass;
  final T className;
  CDropDown({@required this.className, @required this.dataClass});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<className>(
      value: dataClass[0],
      underline: Container(),
      isExpanded: true,
      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: dataClass.map((className user) {
        return  DropdownMenuItem<className>(
          value: user,
          child:  Text(
            user.name),
          );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: null,
    );
  }
}
```

for example:

```dart
class User {
  const User(this.id,this.name);

  final String name;
  final int id;
}
List<User> users = <User>[const User(1,'Foo'), const User(2,'Bar')];
CDropDown(className:User, dataClass :users );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an suggestion

```
class CDropDown<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> dataClass;
  final Widget Function(T) itemBuilder;
  CDropDown({@required this.dataClass, @required this.itemBuilder});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<T>(
      value: dataClass[0],
      underline: Container(),
      isExpanded: true,
      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: dataClass.map((T user) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<T>(
          value: user,
          child: itemBuilder(user),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: null,
    );
  }
}
```

I add `itemBuilder`, the reason is that when I call `user.name` in `CDropDown`, it will show `The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'T'.`. And it should use like

```
class User {
  const User(this.id,this.name);

  final String name;
  final int id;
}
List<User> users = <User>[const User(1,'Foo'), const User(2,'Bar')];
CDropDown<User>(dataClass :users, itemBuilder:(user){return Text(user.name);} );
```

Comment: Thanks so much, how you can `user.name` outside of `CDropDown` class?

Comment: Becasue when you call `CDropDown<User>`, you defined `T` as `User`. So you can call `user.name` in constructor.